# How to show image using Image Url in both android and ios using xamarin forms Xaml page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to show image using image URL but what my problem is If we give the image URL to the image source, image show only Ios, doesn't show in android. I want to show images in both android and Ios. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the url that is not working?

Comment: Can you please post your code to show the image , so that it'll be easy to answer your question ? By the way , this link may be useful for you https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4323/image-from-url-in-imageview

Answer (score 0):

It should work, otherwise, you can try FFimageloading https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading